# Difference between String[] and Array<String>

Tags: java, arrays, types

I'm new to Java and I can't figure out what the difference between `String[]` and `Array<String>` is. And how do I actually count how many entries a `String[]` Array has?
Thanks!

Comment: What's `Array<String>`? I can't find any `Array<T>` class in the [JDK reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), and my JDK's `javac` won't let me compile an `Array<String> foo;` declaration. There's `ArrayList<T>`, but that's something else entirely.

Comment: Probably IDE autocompletion gave him the java.lang.reflect.Array class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String[]` - is an array

`Array` - is a part of reflection API which you shouldn't bother about until you get more experience in java.

`String[] a = new String[length];` - is a proper instantiation of array

`a.length` - returns length of the array

Comment: I had to wait 10 Minutes before the system let me do that ;)

Answer (score 8):

> And how do I actually count how many entries a String[] Array has?

```
if(strArr !=null){
  strArr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Main difference: String[] is not resizable.

Length of String[]: use .length property.