# Differences between String[] and listArray<String>

Tags: android, string, arraylist

Like the title, I would like to know the differences between String[] and ListArray[String], are they same to some extent.

Comment: Looks similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662630/difference-between-string-and-arraystring).  Don't let the question title fool you, the intent of the asker seemed to be "Difference between String[] and ArrayList<String>"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String[] is an array of Strings while ArrayList is a generic class which takes different types of objects (here it takes Strings). Therefore you can only perform normal array operations with String[]. However, you can use additional, convenient utilities such as isEmpty(), iterator, etc with ArrayList since it also implements Collection Interface.

Answer (score 20):

An array `String[]` cannot expand its size. You can initialize it once giving it a permanent size:

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[20]();
myStringArray[0] = "Test";
```

An `ArrayList<String>` is variable in size. You can add and remove items dynamically:

```
ArrayList<String> myStringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
myStringArrayList.add("Test");
myStringArrayList.remove(0);
```

Furthermore, you can sort, clear, addall, and a lot more functions you can use while using an `ArrayList`.

Comment: does it mean that both String[] and ArrayList<String> store the same type data?

Comment: @HeikiCyan In this case both store Strings.

Comment: Which is more efficient

Answer (score 3):

ArrayList has some neat methods, such as add(), remove(), contains()